# Which transport protocols does displayport support?

Tags: hdmi, dvi, displayport

It is my understanding that devices with a displayport output and displayport cables are able to output multiple different protocols without any active conversion hardware on the cable.

The ones that I am aware of is DVI over displayport. I think HDMI over display port is also possible.

What is the complete list of protocols that displayport supports. Are these built in to the specification or are they optional extras that a GPU may support?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature is called "DisplayPort Dual-Mode" which includes DVI and HDMI support.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#DisplayPort_dual-mode_(DP++))

> Dual-mode is an optional feature, so not all DisplayPort sources necessarily support DVI/HDMI passive adapters, though in practice nearly all devices do.